# Connecting to Facebook

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using the IBM Watson-Conversation example on how to connect to Facebook.  But I can't get past copying the connector info to Github.  I'm following the automated process but I keep getting the error below.  Can't see any issues on Github, and the repository is empty.  Any thoughts?

*The integration could not be set up. Check the settings and try again.
Reason: An error occurred while cloning the git repository. Error details: Invalid repository URL. Unable to connect to: https://github.com/davidmackenziejtge/conversation-connector-1.git. Please go to GitHub to either delete or rename the empty repository before trying again.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't given the automated process write access to your github repository. This would have been through a browser message asking for permission when you initiated the process.

Comment: Thansk.  It went through the Oauth process when it connected.  Is there an additional step after that to give it write access?

Comment: The OAuth process should have done it. I see you have an empty project in your git repo, with a similar name. How was that created, as it is empty, maybe you can remove it.

Comment: It creates that everytime I try to do the transfer, but then doesn't get any further.  I've been round the loop of deleting it, and then trying again.  But I always hit the same problem.

Comment: Any reason that your existing project is https://github.com/davidmackenziejtge/conversation-connector and the invalid url attempt is to https://github.com/davidmackenziejtge/conversation-connector-1 ?

Comment: Basically it's copying across the files to my directory.  I've tried a number of different directory names when the previous attempts has failed.  So the error message is just the latest response.